# how to plot table values into a graph using qcustomplot?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qcustomplot

I have an application where the data is displayed on a table widget. But now I want to plot the graph on a custom plot by giving values for x-axis from the table widget and y-axis from my labels.

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]